# Complete specific filenames and directories

Tags: bash, bash-completion

If I want Bash to complete only filenames with extension `.foo` for the command `bar` I can run

```
$ complete -f -X '!*.foo' bar
```

This, however, disables completion of directories preceding a `.foo` file. How do I preserve completion of directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
complete -f -o plusdirs -X '!*.foo' bar
```

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed the section "Programmable Completion" in the Bash manual but for some reason I missed it.